# Ubuntu 13.04 create new wordpress theme from scratch problems

Tags: theme-development, linux

I'm new to wordpress. I tried to create new theme, basically I just copied files from default theme and changed it's name, URI etc. But my theme is not showing in wordpress. Can you tell what steps are required to make new theme in Ubuntu.

Comment: Why do you think this is related to the operating system? Does it show up on other systems?

Comment: Because Linux works differently then Windows for example. When I installed wordpress I had to tweak permissions so maybe I did something wrong. I followed tutorial on youtube about creating new theme, and author of tutorial have no problems, but mine theme just doesn't show up.

Comment: Does your theme have both `style.css` and `index.php`? Do you have WP installed in multisite configuration?

Comment: I coppied existing theme (default) into new directory, I only changed name of folder which contains theme and name of theme inside style.css. And I can't see that 'new' theme.